# Delete directories that contain a certain file

Tags: shell, find, directory, rm

I want to find all directories that contain a certain file and then delete those directories. With

`find . -name thatcertainfile -execdir pwd \;`

I get a list of all the directories I want to delete, but how could I delete all those directories on the fly? Note, that I want to delete the whole directory and not just the file itself, where I could use

`find . -name thatcertainfile -exec rm -r {} \;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this command:

`rm -rf $(find . -name thatcertainfile -execdir pwd \;)`

It should say to the `rm -rf` that what it had to remove is the output of your command.
For example, if your command's output was `/home/guest/Documents` the command I showed would translate on `rm -rf /home/guest/Documents`.

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!

Comment: Was about to do that, however, SE seemingly has a time delay on that, which prevents accepting an answer for a few minutes :)

Comment: This mostly works, but will break on directories containing spaces, tabs, shell glob characters, etc (all of which are valid chars in filenames and dirnames - the only chars that aren't are `/` and NUL).  It would be safer to use `find ... | xargs -d '\n' rm -rf`,  that will work on any directory name except those containing newlines.  Unfortunately, I don't think there's any way to use NUL-terminated file/dirnames (which would have been better) when you rely on the output of `-exec` or `-execdir` for the list of files/dirs.

Comment: That's completely true. I try to never use directories or files names containing spaces so I usually don't take care about them but It could be a possible situation.

Comment: If you create a directory `mkdir -p './ /* /thatcertainfile'` just before you run this command, you will end up running `rm -rf /*`.  Let's say you're not `root`; if you create a directory `mkdir -p "./ $HOME/ /thatcertainfile"` you will end up forcefully removing your entire home directory.  I'd recommend you **never** use the command given in this answer, under *any* circumstances.  (At *least* use `rm -ri` instead, which will prompt you for each deletion.)

Comment: @cas is right, except that it may not simply break but could be a major security problem.  And, if you have GNU coreutils, you could use `find ... -print0 | xargs -0 ...`

Comment: true, but the solution isn't as simple as just using `-print0 | xargs -0` (otherwise `-exec` would work equally well, or better since it doesn't need to run `xargs`).  the OP wants to delete the entire **directory** containing `thatcertainfile`, not just the file itself.  hence the `-execdir pwd \;`.

Comment: BTW, there are some things I'd be willing to risk using the output of `$(find ...)` with, but `rm -rf` is **NOT** one of them.  Even if i knew there were no unusual file/dir names being output, the combination of `rm -rf` and shell-globbing of unknown filenames would make me extremely nervous.  Just seeing a command like that would make me think "WTF am i doing?  find a better way!"

Answer (score 2):

Given a path to the file `./some/where/thatcertainfile`, stripping off the final `/thatcertainfile` gives you a path to the directory. Launch a shell to be able to use string manipulation on the path.

```
find . -name thatcertainfile -exec sh -c 'rm -r "${0%/*}"' {} \;
```

Alternatively, use zsh. To transform a path into the name of the containing directory, use the `:h` [history modifier](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Modifiers) via a [glob qualifier](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Glob-Qualifiers).

```
rm -rf **/thatcertainfile(N:h)
```

(Obviously, test this first before running it with `rm`!)

Answer (score 0):

This pipeline should do the job and be safe from directories with spaces in their names.

```
find . -name thatcertainfile -print0 | xargs --null dirname -z | xargs --null rm -r
```

If anyone sees a problem with this I would like to know.

Comment: Support for `find -print0` and `xargs --null` required, e.g. a GNU-based environment. Those aren't POSIX.

Comment: If no files are found, you get an error from dirname.